# changes the sign of a continuous $f(x)$ with period 2$\pi$ at least 2n+2 times on a interval $[a,b]$ with $b-a>2\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

Let $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $2\pi$, if there exists $n \geq 1, n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) dx = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \sin xdx= \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos xdx=...= \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \sin nx dx=\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos nx dx=0
 \end{equation}

for any interval $[a,b]$, for which $b-a > 2\pi$, prove that the changes of sign of the function $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ at least $2n+2$ times

Comment: Can anybody tell me, which branches of the mathematics this problem belongs to?

Comment: Try to use the fact that for any given $2n$ points on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ there is a linear combination of 1 $\sin kx, \cos kx$ for $1\leq k \leq n$ which has zeroed precisely at the given $2n$ points.